# Insert a string before a matching string or at the end using regex

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds

I have a requirement where the string has to contain `_exact`. I am using Java.

- If the string has a locale (`_en` or `_ja`) at the end, add _exact before the locale.
- If `_exact` is already present, don't add it again.
- If no locale at the end, and no exact, add `_exact` at the end of the string.

E.g.:

- `something` -> `something_exact`
- `something_en` -> `something_exact_en`
- `something_ja` -> `something_exact_ja`
- `something_exact_en` -> `something_exact_en`
- `something_exact` -> `something_exact`

I spent some time and came up with 2 regex that, if ran in succession on the same string, make it possible. I am not sure if they cover all the possible cases though.

> `^(.*)(?<!_exact)(_(?:en|ja))$`
>
> `^(.*)(?<!_exact)(?<!_(?:en|ja))$`

If anybody could help me come up with just 1 regex that does the job, it would be great! Thank you!

Comment: Try https://regex101.com/r/tm0esC/1

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Your regex seems to be working with all the strings I have. I will accept your answer if you post the regex in the answer section. Thank you!

Comment: anubhava's regex is almost the same, a tiny bit optimized. Just `.+?` matches 1 or more chars , and I used `.*?`, 0 or more chars at the start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
str = str.replaceAll("^(?!.*_exact(?:_en|_ja)?$)(.+?)(_en|_ja)?$", "$1_exact$2");
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/OsjRVc/2)

- `(?!.*_exact(?:_en|_ja)?$)` is a negative lookahead that skips inputs that ends with `_exact` or `_exact_en` or `_exact_ja`.

Comment: This works! But Wiktor's regex also works, and since he answered first, I would accept his answer. Unless you find an issue with it?
Thank you for your answer as well!

Comment: I just checked  Wiktor's regex. No I don't find any issue with that as both regex are almost similar.